# Rails - wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, before-filter

I'm beginning with Rails for some days now. I'm trying to make a form application that requires the users to be logged in in every case.

So I made the user login Railcast : http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

Now, I need to make the login required in my other controllers, so the user can't access the whole application without being logged in.
I tryed this method :

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  helper_method :current_user

  private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def logged_in
    return true if current_user 
  end 

  def login_required 
    if logged_in false
      redirect_to log_in_path and return false 
     end                                                                                                                    
  end 

end
```

**categories_controller.rb**

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :login_required
  def new

  def index
     @categories = Categorie.all
  end
```

It returns me this error :

ArgumentError in CategoriesController#index
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

```
 Extracted source (around line #14):    
    def logged_in
        return true if current_user
    end
```

Does my before_filter :login_required needs something else ?
I don't really understand this error.

Comment: can you show the CategoriesController, index method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined a method named `logged_in` which take no arguments but you are calling it with 1 argument:

```
if logged_in(false)
```

You should be doing:

```
if logged_in
```

Your code should probably look like this:

```
def logged_in
  current_user 
end 

def login_required 
  return false if logged_in
  redirect_to log_in_path
end
```

Comment: Oh great ! It seems to work now, thanks !
I turned it into "if !logged_in" and it redirects me to the log_in form.
So, if I understand, this "before_filter" is a Rails native function, and ":login_required" calls my application_controller.rb def login_required function ?

Comment: You can use `unless` if you want.

Comment: When you do `before_filter :foo`, rails will call the method `foo` in the current controller (or its parents) yes.

Comment: Ok, so as application_controller is the parent of my categories_controller, it looks first into categories_controller, finds nothing and searches in application_controller !